# Plotting multiple density plots python

Tags: python, pandas, density-plot

I'm trying to plot multiple density plots from the same pandas df, but getting one plot with all the data on it. any suggestions how to make separate plots for every element of my List?

```
for i in List:
    ax = df[i].plot(kind='density',  colormap="Set2", label='')
    plt.axvline(point_of_interest, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, color='r', label="Current Price")
    plt.title(i)
    ax.legend(loc='lower center',  bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.25), ncol=2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in List:
    ax = df[i].plot(kind='density',  colormap="Set2", label='')
    plt.axvline(point_of_interest, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, color='r', label="Current Price")
    plt.title(i)
    ax.legend(loc='lower center',  bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.25), ncol=2)
    plt.figure()
```

This will make a new figure each iteration through the loop